# C malloc function size

Tags: c, memory-management, casting, malloc, sizeof

So I have this little tricky question I need to answer:

On which segment in memory is c+9 pointing to if the function is:

```
void f() 
 { 
  int *c=(int*)malloc(10); 
 }
```

I think I know how malloc works, and I looked up other questions, so this should allocate 10 bytes of memory and return the adress of the first one, plus it will cast it to int.

So because `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes, I thought that there wouldn't be enough space for 9 integers, and c+9 would point to some memory outside the range of the allocated memory and it would return an error, but no, the program works just fine, as if there was `10*sizeof(int)` allocated. So where am I making a mistake?

Comment: `c + 9` is the same as `&c[9]`, but assuming that `c` is really the pointer to an array of at least 10 elements. Which is not the case in your code.

Comment: I know that, but this code up here works fine when I use it, I am not making a program, this is a question. When I make a program I use malloc( 10 * sizeof (int) ) for example. But this is a question to test my knowledge of how C works.

Comment: You have undefined behavior when you are using memory out of range. In most situations you will not get any compile time error.  It does also not have to throw an exception. Furthermore the compiler may optimize the memory access away if you doesn't need it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mistake is believing that it *works just fine*.

Yes, it probably runs, yes, it probably doesn't segfault, but no, it is not correct.

> So because sizeof(int) is 4 bytes, I thought that there wouldn't be enough space for 9 integers, and c+9 would point to some memory outside the range of the allocated memory

This is correct

> and it would return an error

But this is unfortunately not correct in every case. The OS can only give out space in full pages, this means you can only get space in multiples of 4096 bytes (one page). This means, even though malloc (which is implemented in userspace) gives you 10 bytes, your program will have at least 4096 bytes from the OS. **BUT**: malloc will *eventually* give you out more unallocated space from this one page you got and then it *will* probably introduce a bug.

TLDR: This is UB, even though it looks like it works, never do this.

Answer (score 4):

You're making the mistake in assuming that undefined behavior implies that something "bad" is guaranteed to happen. Accessing `c[9]` in your case is undefined behavior as you haven't `malloc`ed enough memory - and is something that you should not do.

Undefined behavior means that the standard allow for **any** behavior. For this particular error you would often get an non-localized misbehavior, accessing `c[9]` would work apparently fine and no odd things happens when you do it, but then in an unrelated piece of code accessing an unrelated piece of data results in error. Often these kind of mistakes would also corrupt the data used by the memory allocation system which may make `malloc` and `free` to misbehave.

Answer (score 3):

C programs will not return an error if you poke outside of the assigned memory range. The result is not defined, it may hang or (apparently) work fine. But it is not fine.

Comment: So I could have accesed some other programs memory and possibly crash it?

Comment: Yes. Or maybe malloc assigned 16 bytes instead of 10. But you can't know.

Comment: @Nebeski no, thats not possible in modern OSes because of virtual memory management.

Comment: who said anything about modern OS? You can use C in systems without even an OS.

Comment: If your program runs directly as a _kernel_ or whatever there are no other programs to crash.

Comment: "C programs will not return an error if you poke outside of the assigned memory range." is a defined behavior.  As OP's case is undefined behavior, it may return an error, it may not.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that `malloc` gives you 10 characters (usually 8-bit bytes). Allocating an area for `int`s that is not a multiple of `int` size is in itself fishy... but not illegal. The resulting address is interpreted as a pointer to an `int` (typically 32 bits), and you are asking for the address 9 `int` beyond the start of the allocated area. That in itself is fine, but trying to access that is undefined behaviour: anything might happen, including whatever you expect naïvely, nothing whatsoever, crash, or end the universe. What will *usually* happen is that you get assigned memory from a bigger area containing other objects and free space (and the extra data `malloc` uses to keep track of the whole mess). *Reading* there causes no harm, *writing* could damage other data or mess up `malloc`'s data structures, leading to mysterious behaviour/crashes later on. If you are lucky, the new space is allocated at a boundary, and out-of-limits access gives a  segmentation fault, pointing at the culprit.